# Не работает print вставленный в модуль стандартной библиотеки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучаю дебри работы модуля `datetime` из стандартной библиотеки.  Некоторые моменты непонятны, и хочется "разобрать их по частям".  Суть не в этом, приведу пример.  Вот изменённый метод класса `datetime` (Кстати, почему название класса с буквы нижнего регистра?  Вроде "принято" с верхнего.) файла `datetime.py`:

```
def timestamp(self):
    "Return POSIX timestamp as float"
    print("DT 0\t")
    if self._tzinfo is None:
        s = self._mktime()
        print("DT 1\t", s)
        return s + self.microsecond / 1e6
    else:
        print("DT 2\t", self, _EPOCH, self - _EPOCH)
        return (self - _EPOCH).total_seconds()
```

Как видно, я добавил несколько функций `print`, но почему то в консоль они ничего не выводят:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.today().timestamp()
1551994604.500423
>>> now = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> now.timestamp()
1551994607.447423
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Скорее всего ответ на ваш вопрос находится в самом конце файла `datetime.py`, в строчке `from _datetime import *`

Comment: @andreymal Тоже обращал внимание на эту конструкцию, но подумал что к вопросу она прямого отношения не имеет и не спросил, но раз уж зашла речь.  Что означает эта конструкция (в т.ч. и после этой строки) и для чего она нужна?  Модуля `_datetime` вроде нет.

Comment: Да, действительно, закомментировав ту конструкцию, `print` стал работать.

Comment: Он есть (в моём линуксе находится в `/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_datetime.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`), написан [на языке Си](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_datetimemodule.c) и призван улучшить производительность

Comment: У меня нет директории `lib-dynload`, и поиск по файлу `_datetime` в папке `C:\Python36` ничего не дал.

Comment: А в Windows он почему-то встроен прямо в python37.dll

Comment: @andreymal Теперь понятно, спасибо.  Непонятно только вот что, зачем реализацию писать на Питоне, если есть более быстрая реализация на Си?

Comment: @froxxendsg это называется fallback-реализация: если для текущей платформы не нашлась быстрая нативная реализация, то используется медленная, но переносимая.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Понятно, спасибо.